# ??? Attempt to reference field of non-structure array. Error

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

So far from what I have read this error can be caused by confusing or redundant naming within the program but I don't think that is the issue here since everything is declared clearly. From what I can see in this my issue is coming from the declaration of piecewise that is then being run through integration below and therefor the program is attempting to access a array cell that doesn't exist. If this is the case I have so far been stumped at how to fix this issue. Any assistance with this problem would be greatly appreciated.

```
syms t k n

fct = @(t)evalin(symengine,['subs(piecewise([0 <= t and t < 2,',...
'sin((Pi*t^2)/4)],[t <= 2 and t < 3, 5*t-t^2-6], [t <=3 and t < 4, 0],',...
                '[Otherwise, t-4]),t=',regexprep(mat2str(x),' ',','),')']);

evalin(symengine,'assume(k,Type::Integer)');

a = @(fct,t,k) int(fct*cos(k*pi*t/4)/4,t,-2,8);
b = @(fct,t,k) int(fct*sin(k*pi*t/4)/4,t,-2,8);

FourierSeries = @(fct,t,n) a(fct,t,0)/4 + ...
symsum(a(fct,t,k)*cos(k*pi*t/4) + b(fct,t,k)*sin(k*pi*t/4),k,1,n);

pretty(FourierSeries(t,25,1))



ezplot(FourierSeries(t,25,1),-2,8)
hold on
ezplot(fct,-2,8)
hold off
title('Partial sum with n=25')
```

The complete error text is as follows:

> ??? Attempt to reference field of non-structure array.
>
> Error in ==> sym.int at 56
>          r = mupadmex('symobj::intdef',f.s,x.s,a.s,b.s);
>
> Error in ==> @(fct,t,k)int(fct*cos(k*pi*t/4)/4,t,-2,8)
>
> Error in ==>
>   @(fct,t,n)a(fct,t,0)/4+symsum(a(fct,t,k)*cos(k*pi*t/4)+b(fct,t,k)*sin(k*pi*t/4),k,1,n)
>
> Error in ==> FourierProgram at 16 pretty(FourierSeries(t,25,1))

Comment: When it says ??? Attempt to reference field of non-structure array. is this simply a data type error? If so could the original 'fct' in my program be easily converted over to a structure array or actually defined as one in the first place using something like cell2struct?

Comment: Please see [existing questions with this error message](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22%3F%3F%3F+Attempt+to+reference+field+of+non-structure+array%22) and try the solutions there. If nothing works, please update your question with that info :)

Answer (score 0):

This was asked long ago, but I'll provide an answer since one was never given.

As your error indicates, the issue is with this line and how the anonymous function `a` is called:

```
a = @(fct,t,k) int(fct*cos(k*pi*t/4)/4,t,-2,8);
```

The [`sym/int`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/int.html) function expects the second argument (the variable with which the integration is performed with respect to) to be a symbolic variable. However, you're calling `FourierSeries(t,25,1)`, which passes the value `25` as the integration variable.

This bit of code should replicate the issue in your `version` of Matlab (back in 2011 when this was asked):

```
 syms t k;
 int(t*cos(k*pi*t/4)/4,25,-2,8)
```

However, in R2015a I now get a different (and a bit clearer) error message:

> Cannot integrate with respect to ''. The integration variable must be a symbolic variable.